# wrong voltage reading with DMM after a voltage divider

Tags: arduino, voltage-divider

SN04N is a proximity sensor. It is powered with 12V from a bench PSU. That 12V also goes through a buck that produces a 5V rail to feed an Arduino Mega and many other modules. Grounds are common. SN04N has 3 pins : 1 is vcc, 2 is gnd, 3 is the "data" output. Output goes low when the sensor is close to a metal object. It is high at 12v otherwise.

Since I cannot forward that 12V data to the Arduino directly to digitalread it, I set up a voltage divider. R1 is 5.1K, R2 is 3.6K. Input voltage being 12V, I expect the divider to output 5V. But my DMM reads 2.3V. Why ?

Here is the schematic, simplified because the project is too spaghetti :
[image]

Comment: What does the output of the voltage drivider read if it is disconnected from its load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no datasheet to verify, but I suspect this is what's happening:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRr8pf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The NPN open collector output is normally pulled up internally by a resistor and shorted to ground through the transistor when the output is active.  Connecting your voltage divider to the output "adds on" to the existing pullup resistor so your divider will have a larger "top" resistance than you planned for.  Plugging in your numbers gives a calculated Rpu of 10k, which seems on point.  You will just need to adjust your divider to account for this.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is correct.

Your proximity sensor is an NPN-type output sensor.
With internal \$10k\Omega\$ pull-up resistor.

So the actual circuit looks like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQfCly.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

[source](https://www.ampul.eu/en/limit-switches/4596-inductive-sensor-sn04-n2-npn-nc)

Thus, the output voltage is

$$V_{OUT} = 12\:V * \frac{3.6k\Omega}{10k\Omega+5.1k\Omega+3.6k\Omega} = 2.31 \:V$$

The mystery is solved.